# boost compile error for shared_array.hpp

Tags: boost

```
#ifndef __NSFOCUS_URL_RULE_H__
#define __NSFOCUS_URL_RULE_H__
#include "engine/packet.h"
#include "engine/firewall/FireWall.h"
#include "include/DomParser.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>

namespace nsfocus
{

class UrlRule : public FireWallRuleBase
{
private:
        std::set<int> m_cats;            
        unsigned int m_url_action;                                 
        bool CheckURLCat(Packet& p, std::string& 
category,boost::shared_array<unsigned short>& pCatID,unsigned short& nSize);

public:
        UrlRule(void) : FireWallRuleBase(), m_url_action(0x4000) {}
        virtual ~UrlRule(void) {}
        virtual void Parse(xercesc::DOMNode* node);
        void ParseNoFwInfo(xercesc::DOMNode* node);
        void ParseFwInfo(xercesc::DOMNode* node);
        virtual bool isMatch(Packet& p, std::string& 
category,boost::shared_array<unsigned short>& pCatID,unsigned short& nSize);
        virtual bool isProfileMatch(Packet& p, std::string& 
category,boost::shared_array<unsigned short>& pCatID,unsigned short& nSize);
        unsigned int GetAction(void)
        {
                return m_url_action;
        }
};

} 

#endif
```

With the errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/core/demangle.hpp:29:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/core/typeinfo.hpp:119,
                 from /usr/include/boost/detail/sp_typeinfo.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_sync.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp:72,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_array.hpp:17,
                 from aclass/engine/firewall/UrlRule.h:17,
                 from aclass/engine/firewall/FirewallCtrl.h:14,
                 from aclass/class_main.cpp:23:
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:214:3: error: expected class-name before '{' token
   {
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h: In constructor '__cxxabiv1::__fundamental_type_info::__fundamental_type_info(const char*)':
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:217:62: error: expected class-name before '(' token
     __fundamental_type_info(const char* __n) : std::type_info(__n) { }
                                                              ^
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:217:62: error: expected '{' before '(' token
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:225:3: error: expected class-name before '{' token
   {
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h: In constructor '__cxxabiv1::__array_type_info::__array_type_info(const char*)':
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:228:56: error: expected class-name before '(' token
     __array_type_info(const char* __n) : std::type_info(__n) { }
```

[image]

Comment: Please detail more information.... please don't just paste info like that and wait for us to solve your problems.

Comment: my code are move from intel cpu to other platfrom that changed from debian. in intel platform can compiled

Comment: What do you mean "other platform"? Can you _name_ it and the compiler flags used? Perhaps you need to compile without type information:

Comment: the platform name is shenwei，the compiler  is the fallow：

Comment: Using COLLECT_GCC=g++ COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/sw_64sw2-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.1/lto-wrapperTarget: sw_64sw2-unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: Configured with: ../gcc-5.1.1/configure --prefix=/usr --with-gmp=/usr/lib_for_gcc --with-mpfr=/usr/lib_for_gcc --with-isl=/usr/lib_for_gcc --with-mpc=/usr/lib_for_gcc --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go,java,lto --build=sw_64sw2-unknown-linux-gnu --host=sw_64sw2-unknown-linux-gnu --target=sw_64sw2-unknown-linux-gnu --disable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-bootstrap --disable-nls --enable-multiarch --enable-browser-plugin --enable-linker-build-id --enable-linker-no-relax
Thread model: posix

Comment: the cpu is Sunway / shenwei

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:214:3: error: expected class-name before '{' token
   {
   ^
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h: In constructor '__cxxabiv1::__fundamental_type_info::__fundamental_type_info(const char*)':
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cxxabi.h:217:62: error: expected class-name before '(' token
     __fundamental_type_info(const char* __n) : std::type_info(__n) { }
```

These indicate that the following lines of code:

```
  class __fundamental_type_info : public std::type_info
  {
  public:
    explicit
    __fundamental_type_info(const char* __n) : std::type_info(__n) { }
```

do not compile becuase `std::type_info` is not a type. Since, however, `<typeinfo>` is being included right above that, this leads me to suspect that one of your headers includes a macro definition like

#define type_info ...

(where `...` may be empty).

> I'd suggest inspecting the preprocessed source.

### Additional Data Points

The following code compiles fine on my box:

```
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>

namespace nsfocus {

struct FireWallRuleBase {};
struct Packet {};

class UrlRule : public FireWallRuleBase {
  private:
    std::set<int> m_cats;
    unsigned int m_url_action;
    bool CheckURLCat(Packet &p, std::string &category, boost::shared_array<unsigned short> &pCatID, unsigned short &nSize);

  public:
    UrlRule(void) : FireWallRuleBase(), m_url_action(0x4000) {}
    virtual ~UrlRule(void) {}
    virtual void Parse(xercesc::DOMNode *node);
    void ParseNoFwInfo(xercesc::DOMNode *node);
    void ParseFwInfo(xercesc::DOMNode *node);
    virtual bool isMatch(Packet &p, std::string &category, boost::shared_array<unsigned short> &pCatID,
                         unsigned short &nSize);
    virtual bool isProfileMatch(Packet &p, std::string &category, boost::shared_array<unsigned short> &pCatID,
                                unsigned short &nSize);
    unsigned int GetAction(void) { return m_url_action; }
};

} // namespace nsfocus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
//using namespace std;
namespace nsfocus {

struct FireWallRuleBase {};
struct Packet {};

class UrlRule : public FireWallRuleBase {
private:
std::set<int> m_cats;
unsigned int m_url_action;
bool CheckURLCat(Packet &p, std::string &category, 
boost::shared_array<unsigned short> &pCatID, unsigned short &nSize);

public:
UrlRule(void) : FireWallRuleBase(), m_url_action(0x4000) {}
virtual ~UrlRule(void) {}
//virtual void Parse(xercesc::DOMNode *node);
//void ParseNoFwInfo(xercesc::DOMNode *node);
//void ParseFwInfo(xercesc::DOMNode *node);
virtual bool isMatch(Packet &p, std::string &category, 
boost::shared_array<unsigned short> &pCatID,
                     unsigned short &nSize);
    virtual bool isProfileMatch(Packet &p, std::string &category, 
boost::shared_array<unsigned short> &pCatID,
                            unsigned short &nSize);
    unsigned int GetAction(void) { return m_url_action; }
};

} // namespace nsfocus
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFXVj.png)